# 500 Internal Server error when calling API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am receiving internal server error when calling the API, could be something related to permissions in Azure?

See the code below:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Settings.GetMeUrl))
                        {
                            request.Headers.Accept.Add(Json);

                            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session[SessionKeys.Login.AccessToken].ToString());

using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
//response has internal server error 500 ( see below)
....
}
```

**Exception returned:**
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  request-id: 832422ea-f685-4119-8616-fa544b681467
  client-request-id: 832422ea-f685-4119-8616-fa544b681467
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East US","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_4","ADSiteName":"EST"}}
  Duration: 356.9558
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Sat, 07 May 2016 14:36:11 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Type: application/json
}}

**Request content:**
{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSIsImtpZCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSJ9.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.jn3d3YpyEIWH5mDSXl_G0ugyFSqTa-hwYxAgI4N6b_Fu6y9gWu8acwepztJy4LSuZB327jQg_l2ZQuYIVZCNE-GtB9ZuiUOne5nJghrGvLNM1kgCyg4XnafU8REb88O0JfalB7XbvFBNvPfV9XmoGJ73cIutTz1DDwthMBP0HS2-MnscEr9QBggMsDoHazgSV6j8D6mpvTPRe1AZLZ6el9WuZUleezmEtDXtEU4GuBKSPcUN7fB-wVzW3ed6xyBgQlpb5Znqp6-8hyZ3Iz4wYapn34i353eGAaFC87mAm8kuq1RDXkPAgFN1RPkwX1SWWTQu6q2fdpfbkDVmaiCmnA
}}

Comment: Thanks for reporting this.  I'll file a bug for this on our side.  It looks like you are signing in with a guest user - i.e. your user is from Tenant A, but you are trying to access resources in Tenant B.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem. Now I have another problem, I don't know why with most of API calls work fine, but calling the calendar or events API it returns Bad Request. See the response below:

Comment: {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  request-id: 94230de3-623c-4d8b-9bbe-08ff588b6178
  client-request-id: 94230de3-623c-4d8b-9bbe-08ff588b6178
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"002","Host":"AGSFE_IN_2","ADSiteName":"SAN"}}
  Duration: 581.0659
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Sun, 08 May 2016 19:56:43 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Type: application/json
}}

Comment: I checked logs and see the following license related error message, which was also returned in the response payload: "The organization is marked for removal. If this state is unexpected then please contact Office 365 Support."